# How to handle malformed json for a route with 'defaults: {format: :json}'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a url which is supposed to accept only json:

```
put "/my_url" => "my_controller#my_actio", defaults: {format: :json}
```

When I send malformed json to it, it doesn't make to an "action" at all and instead it throws an exception  somewhere in Rails and thus my app ends up returning the error 500. Namely, that's an unhandaled exception.

How can I fix that?

Comment: The reason for your error is _The middleware that parses parameters `ActionDispatch::ParamsParser` runs before your controller is called, and throws exceptions when invalid JSON is encountered. Hence, capturing that error at the controller is not possible._

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna, I want to capture it somehow to return 422 to a user to imply that it's an error on his side. How?

Comment: @Oddamati the default Rails stack returns HTTP 400 for a malformed JSON payload. You should figure out why you are getting a 500 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you to raise those exception and return `422`.

You'll have to create a file under app/middleware, let's call it `json_parse_errors.rb`

```
# app/middleware/json_parse_errors.rb
class JsonParseErrors
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    begin
      @app.call(env)
    rescue ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError => error
      if env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] =~ /application\/json/
        error_output = "There was a problem in the JSON you submitted: #{error}"
        return [
          400, { "Content-Type" => "application/json" },
          [ { status: 422, error: error_output }.to_json ]
        ]
      else
        raise error
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In your `application.rb`, add the following line

```
config.middleware.use JsonParseErrors
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following middleware for this use case:

In lib/detect_non_json_labeled_json.rb:

```
class DetectNonJsonLabeledJson
  def initialize(app, opts = {})
    @app = app
    @opts = opts
  end

  def call(env)
    if(
        middleware_applies_to_this_request?(env) &&
        request_contains_non_json_labeled_as_json?(env)
    )
      [
        415,
        { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' },
        [ { message: 'Invalid POST body.  Must be parseable as JSON' }.to_json ]
      ]

    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end

  private

  def middleware_applies_to_this_request?(env)
    env['PATH_INFO'].start_with?( @opts[:target_prefix] )
  end

  def request_contains_non_json_labeled_as_json?(env)
    labeled_as_json?(env) && contains_non_json?(env)
  end

  def labeled_as_json?(env)
    env['CONTENT_TYPE'] == 'application/json'
  end

  def contains_non_json?(env)
    JSON.parse( ActionDispatch::Request.new(env).raw_post )
    false

  rescue JSON::ParserError
    true
  end
end
```

In application.rb:

```
require 'detect_non_json_labeled_json'

module YourApplication
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...  
    config.middleware.insert_before(
      ActionDispatch::Static,
      DetectNonJsonLabeledJson,
      { target_prefix: '/' }
    )
  end
end
```

Note this returns a status 415 - unsupported media type.  If you'd like to return 422, just replace the code in the call method.